# Readfile and print only specific contant

Tags: php, html

```
$fh = fopen('http:xxxxxxx.com/rates.php','r') or die($php_errormsg);
echo $fh ;
```

result

```
<div class="Cf_row_v_lft splcolor2 Itemcont"> <div class="Itemdiv"><b>88</b></div> <div> 17.4</div> </div> <div class="Cf_row_v_RHT splcolor2"> <div> <a class="splcolor2" target="_blank" href="/item/0/1/milk"><img style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" data-cfsrc='/item/article/t_49.png' width="22" align='absmiddle' data-cfstyle='margin:0;border:0;'/><noscript><img src='/item/article/t_50.png' width="22" align='absmiddle' style='margin:0;border:0;'/></noscript></a></div> <div><b>NED</b></div> </div> </div> <div class="Cf_row_v_RHT splcolor2 itemcont"> <div class="Itemdiv"><b>133</b></div> <div>20.58</div>  </div>  </div><div class="showhidecontentdadt-3 showhidecontentdadta">This price update at Mar 3 2014</div>
```

i just want to print only data which class="Itemdiv" , `<div>20.58</div>` and `<div class="showhidecontentdadt-3 showhidecontentdadta">This price update at Mar 3 2014</div>` only

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: do you need content with i.e. `<div class="Itemdiv">...content...</div>` or without that container?

Answer (score 0):

CSS helps you! You have to define your print styles inside @media `print {//here}` .
Visit here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: I think he means print, as in echo.. :)

Comment: i want to read products and there rates only and put it on my website in php